# Как добавить видеоплеер на Форму C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, mediaplayer

Пытаюсь добавить видеоуроки для обучающей программы, перечитал множество сайтов. Везде пишут про стандартный плеер от Майков, но у меня нет его в панели элементов, как и в списке COM-компонентов(Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022). Попытался добавить wmp.dll вручную, но и здесь он выдает ошибку: "Не удалось загрузить библиотеку типов". Делал через Web-Browser, он открывает видео, только с костылями и в отдельном окне. И Web-Browser с воспроизведением не подойдет т.к. интернет не будет постоянно на тех компьютерах, на которых будет запускаться та программа. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать wmp.dll в корневую папку проекта где .exe болтается и добавить. А вообще ручное добавление отлично справляется. Не понимаю почему у вас ошибка